# How to control the Step Chart Icons in Omniscript Salesforce

Tags: omniscript

I have an omniscript with three steps 1. CAF 2. Billings 3. Results. When the user is in the Results Step they should not be able to navigate to the previous steps using the step chart. How do I achieve this?

Comment: I am not sure if this is available out of the box , you can check the documentation for that . but If the step chart is not important for your users you can can hide it, or , you can create a variable and use it to condition your steps and set it to true once the user is in the Result step which makes the others steps disappear

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using custom lwc and extend the omniscriptstepchart component and if you want to disable the click in stepchart, like you said. Ideally, You will have to create another lwc and extend the child component of omniscriptstepchart i.e omniscriptstepchartItems where you can disable the click on icons. Last step is to override this in your omniscript by going to Setup--> lwc component override --> add the original component on the left and name of the lwc you created by extending the original component . For eg. StepChart  - "yourCustomLwcStepchart"
And also add your stepchartItems if you're overriding that.

Please find below the documentation for the same. You can download the stepchart and stepchartitems template from here.
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.os_extend_an_omniscript_element_s_lightning_web_component.htm&type=5